# Explain FastText model using SHAP values

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, shap, fasttext

I have trained fastText model and some fully connected network build on its embeddings. I figured out how to use Lime on it: complete example can be found in [Natural Language Processing Is Fun Part 3: Explaining Model Predictions](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/natural-language-processing-is-fun-part-3-explaining-model-predictions-486d8616813c)

The idea is clear - put 1 sentence into Lime, it drop words and generate some new sentences from my and check how score changes.

My next idea - use SHAP values for this.
SHAP values can be used for any deep model, using `DeepExplainer`. Here is a usage example: [Keras LSTM for IMDB Sentiment Classification](https://slundberg.github.io/shap/notebooks/deep_explainer/Keras%20LSTM%20for%20IMDB%20Sentiment%20Classification.html)

But I can't use it for my ensemble, because `DeepExplainer` needs tensors as input, but I want to fed sentences. I don't want to use BoW or TF-IDF for that - I loose fastText power in that situation.
What I want to achieve - get some shap-plots built on words of my sentence.
Is it possible?